# Cleaning text file data after reading line by line without using pandas

Tags: python, file, for-loop, text

Like lets say i have text file data like this..

```
|-------|
|Arsenal|
|-------|
|2021
|-------|
|Rnd|A|W|D|L|Venu|Date|
|R1|Tottenham|1|0|0|Emirates|March|
|R2|Man utd|0|1|0|Old Trafford|March|
|Total|Average|1234|5678|
|Arsenal|
|-------|
|2020|
|-------|
|Rnd|A|W|D|L|Venu|Date|
|R1|Chelsea|1|0|0|Stamford Bridge|March|
|R2|Mancity|0|1|0|Ethiad|March|
|Total|Average|1234|5678|
```

I want to convert this file in to 2D array (list of list)  without using pandas. And hoping for output like this

```
Arsenal 2021 R1 Tottenham 1 0 0 Emirates March
Arsenal 2021 R2 Man utd 0 1 0 Old Trafford March
Arsenal 2020 R1 Chelsea 1 0 0 Stamford Bridge March
Arsenal 2020 R2 Man city  0 1 0 Ethiad March
```

So here i need to ignore `|----|`, `|Rnd|`, `|Total|Average|1234|5678|`, and i need to make `Arsenal` and `2021` attached to the every row and `Arsenal` and `2020` to every row in next year..

I have applied for loop going every line by line and created the list of list. But i couldn't delete the header like (`Rnd,T,W,D,L,Venu, Total`) and `total, average` while going through line by line without using pandas...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you're looking for help with the code you wrote, you'll need to include it. You can [edit] and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: There's a bunch of small changes between your input and output. What's up with that? i.e. `old trafford` -> `Old Trafford`, `Stamforbridge|Feb` -> `Stamford Bridge March`, `Mancity` -> `Man city`, `Marvel|Ethiade` -> `Ethiad March`

Comment: Little tricky to parse that file, something like regex can be used to extract data from it(assuming the file follows the same pattern).

Comment: That was the typo mistake. Really sorry for that.The main output i want is the team name and date in same row as a differnt column. I am new to stackoverflow so are you able to read my text file.

Comment: Like lets say i have text file data like this..

|Arsenal|
|-------|
|2021
|-------|
|Rnd|A|W|D|L|Venu|Date|
|R1|Tottenham|1|0|0|Emirates|March|
|R2|Man utd|0|1|0|Old Trafford|March|
|Total|Average|1234|5678|
|Arsenal|
|-------|
|2020|
|-------|
|Rnd|A|W|D|L|Venu|Date|
|R1|Chelsea|1|0|0|Stamford Bridge|March|
|R2|Mancity|0|1|0|Ethiad|March|
|Total|Average|1234|5678|

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? It may need some if/else to run different code in first lines - to rember  `year` after `Arsenal` - and different code in next lines until you get `Total`. It may need variables like `first_part = True/False` to control which part you have to convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable like `first_part = True/False` to run different code in loop.

You can also use `next(file)` to read next line(s) from file so in first part you can read more lines to get `word` and `year` and set `first_part = False`. In second part you has to only add this `word` and `year` to lines and check if line starts with  `|Total' to change` first_part = True`.

---

Minimal working example.

I uses `io` to simulate file but you should use `open()`.

```
text = '''|Arsenal|
|-------|
|2021
|-------|
|Rnd|A|W|D|L|Venu|Date|
|R1|Tottenham|1|0|0|Emirates|March|
|R2|Man utd|0|1|0|Old Trafford|March|
|Total|Average|1234|5678|
|Arsenal|
|-------|
|2020|
|-------|
|Rnd|A|W|D|L|Venu|Date|
|R1|Chelsea|1|0|0|Stamford Bridge|March|
|R2|Mancity|0|1|0|Ethiad|March|
|Total|Average|1234|5678|'''

import io

#fh = open('data.csv')
fh = io.StringIO(text)

first_part = True

for line in fh:
    if first_part:
        word = line.rstrip('\n').rstrip('|')
        line = next(fh)
        line = next(fh)
        year = line.rstrip('\n').rstrip('|')
        line = next(fh)
        line = next(fh)
        first_part = False
    else:
        if line.startswith('|Total|'):
            first_part = True
        else:
            new_line = word + year + line
            print(new_line, end='')
```

Result:

```
|Arsenal|2021|R1|Tottenham|1|0|0|Emirates|March|
|Arsenal|2021|R2|Man utd|0|1|0|Old Trafford|March|
|Arsenal|2020|R1|Chelsea|1|0|0|Stamford Bridge|March|
|Arsenal|2020|R2|Mancity|0|1|0|Ethiad|March|
```

Comment: My code is like this:
`code`
with open('Arsenal.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith(('| --- |', '| Rnd |','| Totals |','| Averages |')) :
            line= line.strip()
            field= line.split('|')
            print(field)
@furas

Comment: you could show code in question - it will be more readable and more peole will see it.

Comment: thank you so much . |-------| this is just above |Arsenal| at the beginning and i just realize. When I tried the code without |-------| , its perfect.
But my text file first row is |-------| instead of |Arsenal|. What line of code I might need to change

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('Arsenal.txt', 'r') as f:
   for line in f: 
     if not line.startswith(('| --- |', '| Rnd |','| Totals |','| Averages |')) : 
        line= line.strip() 
        field= line.split('|')
        print(field)
```

@furas this is my code I tried